# Doesn't accept the list index?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this peice of code:

```
n = int (input ('Enter the Number of Players: '))
m = [[j] for j in range (0, n)]
all_names= []
i = 0
while n > 1:
    m[i] = input('Player {0}: '.format (i+1))
    all_names.extend ([m[i]])
    if m[i][0] != m[i-1][-1]:
        b= m.pop (i)
        n = n-1
    if all_names.count (m[i]) == 2:
        n = n-1
        b= m.pop (i)
    i = i+1
```

It says the index is out of range (second if clause) 
but I dont get it, why?

Comment: `m[i-1][-1]` is highly suspicious...

Comment: You keep popping stuff off of `m`, but `i` grows all the way to its original length. Add `print(m)` at the top of the `while` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to not answer your question directly, but what you're trying to do seems... really confusing. Python has a sort of rule that there's supposed to be a really clear, clean way of doing things, so if a piece of code looks really funky (especially for such a simple function), it's probably not using the right approach.

If you just want to create a container of names, there are numerous simpler ways of doing it:

```
players=int(input("How many players?\n"))
player_names=set()
while len(player_names)<players:
  player_names.add(input("What is player {}'s name?\n".format(len(player_names)+1)))
```

... will give you a set of unique player names, although this won't be **ordered**. That might matter (your implementation kept order, so maybe it is), and in this case you could still use a list and add a small check to make sure you were adding a new name and not repeatedly adding names:

```
players=int(input("How many players?\n"))
player_names=list()
while len(player_names)<players:
  playname=input("What is player {}'s name?\n".format(len(player_names)+1))
  if playname not in player_names:
    player_names.append(playname)
```

I'm open to someone haranguing me about dodging the question, particularly if there's a purpose/reason for the approach the questioner took.

Answer (score 0):

Length of m decreases every time the code enters the first if clause. However, you increment the value of i in each iteration. So, at the midpoint of length of m (if the 1st clause is entered always) or a little later, the value of i will be bigger than the value of m and you will get an index out of range.

Comment: I am running cases for which if clause if not commenced therefore it should jump over the two if statements and ask n time to enter a new value, how does it decrease the length of M when the if is not true?

Comment: @Fatemeh, it's difficult to understand what you said because of the typos in your comment. I assume, you are asking how does the length of M decreases when both first and second if clauses are false. In that case, the length of M will never decrease. But at the same time, n will also never decrease and hence, the condition for while will never become false. At one point, when the value of i becomes bigger than the original length of m, then you will again get an index out of range error but this time in a new place: m[i] = input(...)